# How to decide where soft line-breaks occur with TextKit?

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

I'm trying to define where soft line breaks occur within my text, and the `NSLayoutManagerDelegate` method `layoutManager(_:shouldBreakLineByWordBeforeCharacterAt:)` seems like the place to start. My problem is it's not getting called, although my other methods are. This is occurring with a basic `UITextView` setup. Under what conditions is this method called - am I looking in the right place?

Here's what my TextKit stack looks like:

```
class DemoTextView: UITextView, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {

    //  MARK: - Init

    required init() {
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: "i will overflow several lines probably just saying")

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()

        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

        textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        //  Super

        super.init(frame: .zero, textContainer: textContainer)

        self.textContainerInset = .zero

        //  Configure Text View

        layoutManager.delegate = self

        self.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    //  Layout Manager

    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager, shouldBreakLineByWordBeforeCharacterAt charIndex: Int) -> Bool {
        print(#function)

        return false
    }

    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager, shouldBreakLineByHyphenatingBeforeCharacterAt charIndex: Int) -> Bool {
        print(#function)

        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: @matt Updated. The stack isn't necessarily entirely custom, though - I've just set a delegate/

Comment: @matt I was trying this out in Playground, using a live view. Perhaps that's it?

Comment: I wash my hands of the whole thing. Playgrounds are the work of the devil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in an actual app, with the text view occupying the entire superview, and `shouldBreakLineByWordBeforeCharacterAt` is called multiple times at launch if the initial string is long, and then again every time the user types a character — exactly as expected.

Comment: That's exactly it, Playgrounds was fudging the issue, using a real app worked. Since you seem to be knowledgable, what I'm really trying to do is absolutely position characters. My initial idea was to use `shouldBreakLineByWordBeforeCharacterAt` to decide where line breaks occur and `NSTextContainer.lineFragmentRect(forProposedRect:)` to decide how 'lines' were positioned. Is this a good approach?

Comment: "what I'm really trying to do is absolutely position characters" That would be a separate (and interesting) question.